# What is the display life of ulcd-43PT TFT LCD Touch panels in terms of pixels and backlight?

Tags: tft

What is the display life of ulcd-43PT TFT LCD Touch panels in terms of pixels and backlight? I want to keep it on in my application for the maximum time (say ten years) in an almost same state (data display).

Comment: I'm just querying with my opposite number in 4D Systems.  Watch this space.

Answer (score 1):

The backlight has a rating of 20,000 hours where at that point the backlight should be 50% of original brightness.

I can't get any information on pixel lifetime.